# Términos y condiciones HTML

Tags: html, formularios, checkbox

Estoy programando un formulario de actualización de contactos, que incluye un apartado de términos y condiciones, cómo puedo hacer para condicionar el checkbox de este? es decir, si el usuario no acepta los términos, el botón de enviar se desactive hasta clickear en el checkbox. Adjunto código en HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Formulario de actualización de datos</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="form-register">
    <h4 align="center">Formulario de actualización de datos Empresa</h4>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre" required>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido" required>
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo" required>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="rut" id="rut" placeholder="Ingrese su RUT (Sin puntos y con guión)" required>

    <input type="checkbox" onclick="agreesubmit(this)" name="condiciones"/> Estoy de acuerdo con los <a href="terminos.html" target="_blank" class="enlace-terminos">términos y condiciones</a> <br/>

    <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    <input class="botons" type="button" value="Deseo eliminar mi contacto">
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero al botón enviar lo deshabilitas con la propiedad `disabled`.
Después con javascript, escuchando el checked por medio de `onChange`, disparás una función (en este caso la llame `cambiarCondiciones`) que analice el check: si esta checkeado, habilite el botón `enviar`, de lo contrario, lo deshabilite nuevamente

```js
const tyc = document.getElementById("condiciones");
const enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");

const cambiarCondiciones = () => tyc.checked ? enviar.disabled = false : enviar.disabled = true
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Formulario de actualización de datos</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="form-register">
    <h4 align="center">Formulario de actualización de datos Empresa</h4>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre" required>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido" required>
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo" required>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="rut" id="rut" placeholder="Ingrese su RUT (Sin puntos y con guión)" required>

    <input type="checkbox" onChange="cambiarCondiciones()" id="condiciones"  name="condiciones"/> Estoy de acuerdo con los <a href="terminos.html" target="_blank" class="enlace-terminos">términos y condiciones</a> <br/>

    <input id="enviar" disabled class="botons" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    <input class="botons" type="button" value="Deseo eliminar mi contacto">
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió de mucho